# Problem with the use of converters in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have in my database a string corresponding to a serialized byte array. I'd like to be able to modify bytes present in that string and add or remove some of them.

I'm converting my string retrieved from my database to my viewmodel to a list of bytes in my XAML via a converter present in my listbox binding. I then use the byte array represented as textboxes with a datatemplate. But the problem is that I'm not able to retrieve changes done in the textboxes back to the listbox and then back to the Serialized string.
What I tried:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ByteArray, Converter={converter:HexStringToListOfBytesConverter}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I'm having an idea about why it isn't working but can't get my head around how to make it work. I think that the converter doesn't affect the textboxes. Ideally the string to byte array conversion should only be used to edit an existing Serialized array. And a new made one from the modifications done should replace the old one.

Comment: Would it not be much easier to do the conversion between string/byte[] in the model or view model? Or just present the full hex-string in a single textbox if your users are familiar with hex values?

Comment: I think you want to be converting the byte array to a hex string and providing the hex string to the TextBox. It looks from what you posted you might have it backwards. Otherwise would you kindly post the converter code? That would probably clarify things.

Comment: @EmperorEto
`{
    if (value is string hexString)
    {
        // Convert hex string to list of bytes
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<byte>>(hexString);
    }
    return null;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is List<byte> bytes)
    {
        // Convert list of bytes to hex string
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bytes.Select(item => (int)item).ToArray());
    }
    return null;
}`

Comment: It is visually working for my listbox, textboxes are showing with the bytes content but I assume that my convertback is not working as I expect. I will try the Jonas answer, doing the conversion in my model or ViewModel

Comment: Ok it looks to me like you have `Convert` and `ConvertBack` flipped. `Convert` is what goes to the `TextBox`, `ConvertBack` is what comes back from the `TextBox`. So you want `Convert` to return the string and `ConvertBack` to return the `byte[]`. Also FYI for future reference it's easier for us to read if you edit the question to include the code rather than post it in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and my converters are, I think, not flipped. What I want is my textboxes to contain my converted array elements coming from the string. I just think that it is not the way to go, as my converter doesn't seems to affect the child textboxes.

Comment: If you could edit the post and put the converter there, instead of in a comment, that would be a lot easier to understand

Comment: "What I want is my textboxes to contain my converted array elements coming from the string" `TextBox` needs to receive a string, so unfortunately what you're saying really doesn't make sense. Why don't you try showing in your question what the current result is vs. what you want it to be? That might make things clearer for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind to a string `TwoWay`. You bind to *properties* of objects, the binding source. In a *TwoWay* binding you can change the value of these properties. This means, *in theory*, you could bind to properties of string to change its content.
Additionally, `string` is immutable.

You must introduce a wrapper type to represent a byte or character representation. This way you can modify the property value of a binding source.

In general, your approach is overly complicated. You can directly work on `string` or even `char`. There is a bult-in compiler conversion between `char` and `byte`. It doesn't make sense to convert a `string` to `byte[]` only to convert it back to `string` for editing in the view. Which human being does not prefer to edit text presented as characters instead of bytes...
I recommend to convert the hex string to a text string and edit those values.

The following example introduces a `ByteValue` wrapper and encapsulates the conversion in a `ByteValueCollection` that you can directly bind to.

The `ByteValue` enables you to edit both the byte value and the character representation.
**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ByteValueCollection Bytes
  {
    get => (ByteValueCollection)GetValue(BytesProperty);
    set => SetValue(BytesProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty BytesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Bytes",
    typeof(ByteValueCollection),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    string hexText = "48616C6C6F"; // Hallo
    this.Bytes = new ByteValueCollection(hexText);

    string hexText = "48 61 6C 6C 6F"; // Hallo
    this.Bytes = new ByteValueCollection(hexText, ' ');

    string hexString = this.Bytes.ToHexString(); // "48616C6C6F"
    string hexString = this.Bytes.ToHexString(' '); // "48 61 6C 6C 6F"
  }
}
```

**MainWIndow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Name="Root">
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Bytes}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ByteValue}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Character}" /> <!-- SHow/edit the text character representation -->
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" /> <!-- Show/edit the byte value -->
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

**ByteValue.cs**

```cs
public class ByteValue : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
  public ByteValue(byte value) => this.Value = value;

  private byte value;
  public byte Value
  {
    get => this.value;
    set
    {
      this.value = (byte)value;
      OnPropertyChanged(null);
    }
  }

  public char Character
  {
    get => (char)this.Value;
    set
    {
      this.Value = (byte)value;
      OnPropertyChanged(null);
    }
  }

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**ByteValueCollection.cs**

```cs
public class ByteValueCollection : ObservableCollection<ByteValue>
{
  public ByteValueCollection()
  {
  }

  public ByteValueCollection(string hexString) : this(hexString, ' ')
  {
  }

  public ByteValueCollection(string hexString, char separator)
  {
    string[] hexTextValues = hexString.Split(separator);
    if (hexTextValues.Length != 1)
    {
      for (int index = 0; index < hexTextValues.Length; index++)
      {
        string hexTextValue = hexTextValues[index];
        byte byteValue = Convert.ToByte(hexTextValue, 16);
        var item = new ByteValue(byteValue);
        Add(item);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      for (int index = 0; index < hexString.Length; index += 2)
      {
        string hexTextValue = hexString.Substring(index, 2);
        byte byteValue = Convert.ToByte(hexTextValue, 16);
        var item = new ByteValue(byteValue);
        Add(item);
      }
    }
  }

  public ByteValueCollection(IEnumerable<ByteValue> collection) : base(collection)
  {
  }

  public ByteValueCollection(List<ByteValue> list) : base(list)
  {
  }

  public byte[] ToByteArray()
  {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[this.Count];
    for (int index = 0; index < bytes.Length; index++)
    {
      byte value = this[index].Value;
      bytes[index] = value;
    }

    return bytes;
  }

  public char[] ToCharArray()
  {
    char[] chars = new char[this.Count];
    for (int index = 0; index < chars.Length; index++)
    {
      char value = this[index].Character;
      chars[index] = value;
    }

    return chars;
  }

  public string ToHexString()
  {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[this.Count];
    for (int index = 0; index < bytes.Length; index++)
    {
      byte value = this[index].Value;
      bytes[index] = value;
    }

    return Convert.ToHexString(bytes);
  }

  public string ToHexString(char separator)
  {
    byte[] bytes = ToByteArray();
    string hexString = Convert.ToHexString(bytes);
    var hexStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(hexString);
    int separatorIndex = 2;
    for (int readInndex = 0; readInndex < this.Count - 1; readInndex++)
    {
        
      hexStringBuilder.Insert(separatorIndex, separator);
      separatorIndex += 3;
    }

    return hexStringBuilder.ToString();
  }
}
```